# Creating a function that returns a variable to ZERO if variable is NaN

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to store the value **"0"** within a variable if the variables calculation returns **"NaN"**

The code only seems to execute if the variable is **">0"**

**Here is my code:**

```
function changeNumber() {
    var average = Math.round((list.rating[0].score)/(list.rating[0].votecount));
    if (isNaN(average))
        return average =0;
    console.log("output"    +average);
}
```

So basically i get some numeric data from a database and do a calculation **"score / votecount"**, which returns the average of something. If the **"score"** and **"votecount"** fields within the database contain no data then my calculation returns **"NaN"**. I would like to change this **"NaN"** to a numeric "0".

Any help in getting this to run would me greatly appreciated.

p.s it is perfectly fine if the database contains no calculatable figures because it means that something has not yet been voted. (just incase you are wondering why i have a NaN value in the first place)

Comment: Your function does return `0` when the calculation returns `NaN`. The problem I see is that it doesn't return anything when it's a valid number.

Comment: I think you should parse your input and output using `parseInt`/`parseFloat` first of all.

Comment: works well.. http://jsfiddle.net/x3mk5zsf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// sample initialization
var score = 10;
var votecount = 'abc';

// first do the division
var division = score/votecount;

// check the division if it is NaN
if(isNaN(division))
  alert('zero'); // or return 0;
else{
  division = Math.round(division); // use division for the rest of the code
  alert(division);
}
```

Note that `Math.round()` wouldnt work if the division is NaN.

Comment: i need to use Math.round to return a "whole number" for later code.

Comment: @Justin I get it. But you need to understand that if the division itself returns a `NaN`, what would `Math.round()` do?

Comment: @Justin Please checkout my updated answer above. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: ,Thansk i understand now.. but .. please see my fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Musicman/qhg99ysy/1/)

Comment: @Justin `0/0 = undefined` is a fact. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Comment: @Justin Thats the reason it doesnt go through. Did you get it?

Comment: @Justin One way to fix this is to check if the values are `0` and then assign `division` to `0`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/qhg99ysy/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeNumber() 
{
  var average = Math.round((list.rating[0].score)/(list.rating[0].votecount));
  return isNaN(average) ? 0 : average;
}
```

Comment: you can assign average variable before the condition

Answer (score 0):

*First* calculate the average, *then* use `Math.round` to round if applicable:

```js
var num1 = changeNumber(101, 'foo');
var num2 = changeNumber(101, 12);

// using short circuit boolean evaluation 
var num3 = Math.round(101/'bar' || 0);
var num4 = Math.round(101/25 || 0);


Helpers.log2Screen('`num1`: ', num1, '<br>`num2`: ', num2,
                   '<br>`num3`: ', num3, '<br>`num4`: ', num4);


function changeNumber(n1, n2) {
    var calc = n1/n2;
    return !isNaN(calc) ? Math.round(calc) : 0;
    // you can also do this in one line using
    // short circuit boolean evaluation (see num3):
    // return Math.round(n1/n2 || 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://kooiinc.github.io/JSHelpers/Helpers-min.js"></script>
```